# How to 'source ~/.profile' and activate virtual environment and run python script from a .sh file

Tags: raspbian-stretch, opencv, computer-vision

I am working on my project and using a raspberry pi 3B+ with raspbian OS. I followed the following link to pip install open cv on my pi using a virtual environment I named 'cv' and it works fine: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/19/pip-install-opencv/

What I am trying to do is I want to activate my virtual environment and to run a particular .py (timer_design) file from a .sh (my_command) file so that I can execute it from a desktop icon for people to use. What I have done so far is:

(i) I have created a .sh (my_command) file and edited it as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
#my_command
cd /home/pi
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
. /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
workon cv
sudo python timer_design.py
```

(ii) To make virtualenvwrapper.sh executable, I used the following command:

```
sudo chmod 777 virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

(iii) Then I made my my_command executable from within my file from my home directory and ran it using this command:

```
./my_command
```

When I ran this, I got the following errors:

```
./my_command: 110: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: function: not found
./my_command: 120: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: Syntax error: "}" unexpected
```

everything works fine when I run the following commands straight into terminal:

```
$source ~/.profile
$workon cv
$python timer_design.py
```

please help :)